# Error UnicodeDecodeError al obtener datos de PostgreSQL usando SQLAlchemy en Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, unicode, encoding

estoy encontrando un error UnicodeDecodeError al intentar obtener datos de una base de datos PostgreSQL usando SQLAlchemy en Python. Aquí está el mensaje de error que estoy obteniendo:

> File "C:\Users\jl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py", line 1139, in fetchall
> self.handle_exception(result, dbapi_cursor, e)
> File "C:\Users\jl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py", line 1080, in handle_exception
> result.connection._handle_dbapi_exception(
> File "C:\Users\jl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2346, in _handle_dbapi_exception
> raise exc_info[1].with_traceback(exc_info[2])
> File "C:\Users\jl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py", line 1135, in fetchall
> rows = dbapi_cursor.fetchall()
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)

El error ocurre cuando intento obtener todas las filas del cursor. Estoy usando la codificación SQL_ASCII en mi cadena de conexión:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@ipservidor:puertoservidor/namedb?client_encoding=SQL_ASCII')
```

Modifique esta cadena de conexión ya tambien lo intente de esta manera

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@ipservidor:puertoservidor/namedb)
```

¿Alguien ha encontrado este problema antes y sabe cómo resolverlo? ¡Cualquier ayuda sería muy apreciada!